# Problem about real square matrix with rank 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\text{rank}(A) = 1$. By working only on real field, show that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $\text{tr}(A) \neq 0$. Here, $\text{tr}(A)$ is the sum of all eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @Servaes Prove that 0 is an eigenvalue of $A$ and it has geometric multiplicity of $n-1$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, $0$ also has algebraic multiplicity of $n-1$, so there is another nonzero eigenvalue, so tr(A) is not zero. On the other hand, if $A$ is not diagonalizable, then $0$ must have algebraic multiplicity of $n$, so that tr(A) must be zero. Is it true?

Comment: Seems fine to me.